# Inappropriate blocking method call warning within a separate Dispatchers.IO block

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Why does the first code snippet produces `Inappropriate blocking method call` warning but not the second one?

```
private fun prepareList() = launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        requireContext().openFileOutput(listFileName, Application.MODE_PRIVATE).use { out ->
            requireContext().assets.open(listFileName).use {
                it.copyTo(out)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun prepareList() = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    requireContext().openFileOutput(listFileName, Application.MODE_PRIVATE).use { out ->
        requireContext().assets.open(listFileName).use {
            it.copyTo(out)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, the lambda for the first launch example is detected as throwing an IOException.

Comment: What is `launch` function in these examples? I ask because you use it outside of any `CoroutineScope`, so this code should not even compile.

Comment: @broot the `launch` is inside an activity coroutine.